# Alternative to the T-SQL AS keyword

Tags: sql, vb.net

Please see the code below:

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration

    Public Class Form1
        Private _ConString As String
        Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            Dim objDR As SqlDataReader
            Dim objCommand As SqlCommand
            Dim objCon As SqlConnection
            Dim id As Integer
            Try
                _ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TestConnection").ToString
                objCon = New SqlConnection(_ConString)
                objCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT Person.URN, Car.URN FROM Person INNER JOIN Car ON Person.URN = Car.URN AND PersonID=1")
                objCommand.Connection = objCon
                objCon.Open()
                objDR = objCommand.ExecuteReader(ConnectionState.Closed)
                Do While objDR.Read
                    id = objDR("URN") 'line 19
                Loop
                objDR.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw
            Finally

            End Try

        End Sub


End Class
```

Please see line 19.  Is it possible to do something similar to this:

```
objDR("Person.URN")
```

When I do: objDR("URN") it returns the CarURN and not the Person URN.  I realise that one solution would be to use the SQL AS keyword i.e.:

```
SELECT Person.URN As PersonURN, Car.URN AS CarURN FROM Person INNER JOIN Car ON Person.URN = Car.URN AND PersonID=1
```

and then: `objDR("PersonURN")`

However, I want to avoid this if possible because of the way the app is designed i.e. it would involve a lot of hard coding.

Comment: I dont think there is any alternative to AS keyword in SQL.

Comment: side issuse, but you should really change this to close your connection as part of the Finally block.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn, i would usually wrap the connection in a Using block.  Can you confirm that it is not necessary to manually close the connection or set the object (objcon) to nothing if you use this approach? Thanks.

Comment: @w0051977 that is correct. If you have a using block for your connection, that will close the connection. But your sample lacks a using block. Instead, the connection is closed by the data reader, which itself could be left hanging open for a while if an exception is thrown at the wrong time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look up the column by index, rather than by name. Either of the following would work:

```
id = objDR(0)
id = objDR.GetInt32(0)
```

Otherwise, your best bet is the "As" keyword or double-quotes (which are the ansi standard) to create an alias.

Comment: Yes, I was aware you could do this but didn't think of it.  I will see if it meets my requirements and pop back later to mark the answer.  +1.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, becuase of the inner join, you do not need to include both in the select clause, as equality is required, so only include either one.

So either

```
SELECT Person.URN 
FROM   Person INNER JOIN 
       Car ON Person.URN = Car.URN AND PersonID=1
```

or

```
SELECT Car.URN 
FROM   Person INNER JOIN 
       Car ON Person.URN = Car.URN AND PersonID=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already are changing the query, and cannot for some reason change the other code, then create a view with the column names as you like, then select from that view.